# how to use a var like as id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to draw into div but first I tried to change the text at  but I can't someone can help me pls? I put in the console $("#uno").attr("id"); and works but if I used consolo.log(x) on my function says undefined.

```
<a href="" onclick="cambio()" value="tres" id="uno" title="">Etiqueta uno</a>
<a href="" onclick="cambio()" id="dos" title="">Etiqueta dos</a>
<a href="" onclick="cambio()" id="tres" title="">Etiqueta tres</a>
<a href="" onclick="cambio()" id="cuatro" title="">Etiqueta cuatro</a>
var x= "";
    function cambio(){
        x = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log(x);
        $(x).text("clickeado");
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I have "x = $(this).attr("id");"

Comment: you dont have an attribute name in the anchor

Comment: You want to update the text?

Comment: You don't even need id ! Just use `$(this).text('click');`

Comment: Yes I want to update the text but just when you clicked each. @Eddie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to prevent the default behaviour by using `event.preventDefault()`. Secondly `$(this)` refers to the current element in context but you are not passing `this` in the click handler.

You can pass the event object and use `event.target` which will give the current element which have triggered the click. Use `event.target.id` to get the `id`

```js
var x = "";

function cambio(elem) {
  event.preventDefault();
  x = event.target.id;
  console.log(x);
  $(event.target).text("clickeado");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" onclick="cambio(event)" value="tres" id="uno" title="">Etiqueta uno</a>
<a href="" onclick="cambio(event)" id="dos" title="">Etiqueta dos</a>
<a href="" onclick="cambio(event)" id="tres" title="">Etiqueta tres</a>
<a href="" onclick="cambio(event)" id="cuatro" title="">Etiqueta cuatro</a>
```

Comment: Thanks now I can continue with my proyect